# How do I fix the error "_this2.push.characterInfo is not a function" in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have seen the solution for other similar questions but it seems like they are all to do with reacts binding system. Anyway, I get the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this2.characterInfo.push is not a function
```

when I try to push some data to an array

```
    populateCell(response) {
  response.forEach((element) => {
    this.characterInfo.push({
      id: element.id,
      name: element.name,
      gender: element.gender,
      location: element.location,
      img: element.image,
    });
  });
},
```

I have declared the array in my vue instance but I still seem to be getting the error.
I'm passing a JSON object in if that makes a difference, I have used typeof to verify this.

```
characterInfo: []
```

This array is populated with objects.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. what is `this.characterInfo`?

Comment: Error is telling you `_this2.characterInfo` is not an array as you are expecting it to be. Code shown does not have `_this2.characterInfo` in it , uses `this.characterInfo`